# Why does VSCode Code Runner not support f-strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, f-string, vscode-code-runner

I have this issue with VSCode and the Code Runner extension and here is the code snippet causing the issue:

```py
class init_error(Exception):
    def __init__(self, comp="Internals"):
        self.component = comp
        self.message = f"Error occurred while initiating {self.component}"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message
```

I first thought it was mistaking the compiler between Python2 and Python3, but after specifying `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and checking that `print("foo")` works, I was fairly certain that it was not a version issue. I have checked that the compiler in Code Runner is set to `3.7.4 64-bit` so I tried running the code through the `Python` extension, and it worked, so I believe this is a Code Runner issue.

Sorry for being long, but lastly, the f-strings are NOT underlined in red and it does not come up as a problem, therefore for some reason, f-strings are considered to be valid syntax, but does not run in only the Code Runner extension.

How can I make Code Runner accept f-strings?

Thank you for the help.

P.S. I don't think this is relevant, but I could have sworn it worked a month ago.

Comment: "does not run" -- that's your interpretation, but what did you observe? Also read [ask] and extract a [mcve]. Further, which version are you running? You can find out the actual Python version from inside Python!

Comment: have you checked the python interpreter uses by VSCode was python3.6 or later?

Comment: To follow up with what @beer44 suggested, run `import sys; print(sys.version_info)` to see what version of Python is being run.

Comment: Ok, I found something wierd: `print(sys.version)` first gave me 2.7.10, but I was using `print()` without any problems. When I added `#!/usr/bin/env python3` I got 3.7.4, and the f-strings worked fine. So thank you...

Answer (score 5):

Below are links to the steps I took to get f-strings to work in vs-Code

1. Search for Code-Runner in Extensions and click on the gear icon 'manage', in the
   dropdown menu click on   Extension Settings

[image]

2. Scroll down to Code-runner Executor Map and click Edit in settings.json

[image]

3. On line 67 change python -u to python3 -u

[image]

Comment: Can you please be more descriptive Steven, i.e. which field on the settings.json file and maybe even a bit extra information or reference on how to change the settings file as well?

Comment: Sorry, I hope it is more descriptive now

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this is settings.json:

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName"
    },
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
"code-runner.ignoreSelection": true,
"code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening to me also when i use within vscode terminal:

```
python filename.py
```

However using below, it works:

```
python3 filename.py
```

Comment: `python` command should normally refer to Python 2. To run Python 3, you have to use `python3`.